# Join tables from multiple sources

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm trying to create a query (which i'll turn into a view later) to perform some training reports. Basically, you as an employee can have training assigned from multiple sources, in this case directly or as part of your job. So you might have something like this

```
select c.id, c.name, c.cost 
from course c 
join job_assignment ja on ja.course_id = c.id
join employee emp on emp.job_id = ja.id
where emp.name = 'Bob'

select c.id, c.name, c.cost
from course c
join personal_assignment pa on pa.course_id = c.id
join employee emp on emp.job_id = pa.id
where emp.name = 'Bob'
```

What I really want is something like

```
select c.id, c.name, c.cost 
from course c
join magic_personal_and_job_assginment_combiner magic 
    on magic.course_id = c.id
join employee emp on emp.id = magic.employee_id
where emp.name = 'Bob'
```

But I don't see how to make the logical connections. I can do it in two queries, but I don't know how to combine them into one.

I'm using Oracle, but I imagine the answer is rooted in plain-Jane SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a union connecting the two existing queries (which you say work) and just add a column to distinguish the source, like so (if I understand your problem correctly):

```
select c.id, c.name, c.cost, 'job assign' as assign_source
  from course c
  join job_assignment ja
    on ja.course_id = c.id
  join employee emp
    on emp.job_id = ja.id
 where emp.name = 'Bob'
union all
select c.id, c.name, c.cost, 'pers assign' as assign_source
  from course c
  join personal_assignment pa
    on pa.course_id = c.id
  join employee emp
    on emp.job_id = pa.id
 where emp.name = 'Bob'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. There's a couple minor steps excluded from the example, but this is perfect. This is what I get for relying so much on hibernate... =) Thanks!

Comment: Finally got my query working. There was a small hiccup trying to do my `connect on` for my job hierarchy, so i did something very bad by hardcoding my hierarchy levels so i can get my demo ready for monday morning haha... I expect velociraptors any second now. But that's okay. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.cost 
FROM course c,  job_assignment ja, employee emp,personal_assignment pa 
WHERE emp.name = 'Bob' AND ( (ja.course_id = c.id AND emp.job_id = ja.id ) OR (pa.course_id = c.id AND emp.job_id = pa.id))
```